# Apply CSS after dynamic form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an iFrame in my page which is hidden to begin with. Then from javascript, I am building a form and submitting. I am setting form.target to the iframe so it loads there.

```
<iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

This is hidden using css display:none

My JS is like this:

```js
const form = document.createElement('form');
const actionUrl = 'http://example.com/';
 form.method = 'post';
 form.action = actionUrl;
 form.target="myIframe";
 //append input fields - leaving out hat loop
 document.body.appendChild(form);
 document.getElementById('myIframe').style.display = "block";
 form.submit();
```

```html
<iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

The whole thing works as I expect it. But since the display:block before the submit, the iframe shows up a second before its content shows up. Is there any way I can set the IFrame display attribute after form.submit()

Comment: Check for an element will show in iframe. If you find it, display the iframe

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to set inline styling of the `<iframe/>` to ensure that the iframe is immedialty hidden during the inital paint:

```
<iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Setting inline styles like this is however usually not recommended - the preferred method of styling is via CSS which in your case could be implemented by updating your HTML to this:

```
<style>
    #myIframe {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

Either approach should produce the desired result with your current JavaScript.